# How to customize the UITextField?

Tags: iphone, ipad

How to Customize UITextField has show in the below picture

.[image]

Comment: http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/01/04/uitextfield-a-complete-api-overview/

Answer (score 1):

```
[textField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[textField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set property **placeholder** of your UITextField object to @"07/28/2011 4x8 Card" and use code from @Akshay

Comment: @ Nekto I am not talking about PlaceHolder for the UITextField .. But any way thanks for the place holder ..... I am here to customize my UITextField in this passion

Answer (score 0):

If you are on iOS3.0+, you can do a custom border using quartzcore:

```
#import<QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

textfield.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
textfield.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0; //Adjust as you see fit.
textfield.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
textfield.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the border style to none and use a custom background image:

```
textfield.background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"];
```